# Are there any alternatives Exchange EWS api?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Im currently using the Exchange EWS api to sync two calendars. There is a customer that does not want open up EWS to the public.

Are there any other methods, apis, etc to CRUD Exchange calendars?

Comment: MAPI is the other Mailbox API that is used by Outlook, although if they haven't allowed EWS externally then they probably don't publish any of the Exchange Endpoint publicly (eg they always expect users to use a VPN etc)

Comment: The industry standard protocol for calendar interchange is CalDAV. Unfortunately, I don't believe Exchange supports it. You may be able to get a third-party gateway or Exchange addon to get support, but you'll probably have to pay money for it.

Answer (score 0):

DavMail is a POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/Carddav/LDAP exchange gateway. It's implemented in Java and should run on any platform.

It's been a while since I've implemented it on local machines for single app use inside a WAN and also on web facing servers as a general gateway into Exchange for Linux users.

I don't know if it plays well with O365 etc, as I haven't needed to find out yet.

Its a SourceForge project with some sponsorship from the French Defense Agency.